# CRUD operation on a web application project on vs 2010 (not web form) with web api

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-applications, asp.net-web-api, crud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET Web Api CRUD operation in VS 2010 web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183092/asp-net-web-api-crud-operation-in-vs-2010-web-application)

I tried to create a CRUD operation on a web application project on vs 2010 (not web form) with Web Api.
I already success returning the value of the controller through the web address 'http://localhost:7031/api/product/',
but when I try with jquery ajax, controller does not return a value.

Bellow is My Code :

Route/Global.asax :

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", // browse with localhost:7031/api/product
                //routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",  // browse with localhost:7031/product
                defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }

        );
        }
```

Controller :

```
namespace MyLabs1.Controller

{

    public class ProductController : ApiController
    {
        NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
        {
            return db.Products.AsEnumerable();
        }
```

Ajax Jquery Page :

```
<script src="Script/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Script/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $('#<%= cviewproduct.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
            getProducts();
        });

    });

function getProducts() {
        $.getJSON("/api/product/",
                function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        var str = val.productName;
                        alert(str)
                    });
                });
    }
```

Any idea, why my code is not working ?

Thank's in advance

Andrian

Comment: are there multiple get methods in the productscontroller. what error are u getting?

Comment: You could have edited this question instead of asking another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183092/asp-net-web-api-crud-operation-in-vs-2010-web-application

Comment: thank's  for your suggestion...