# ASP.NET Web Api CRUD operation in VS 2010 web application

Tags: entity-framework, jquery, asp.net-web-api, crud

I tried to make ASP.NET Web Api CRUD operation in VS 2010 web application, but why the result is not returning all entire row from source table.

This is my code :

Route/Globax.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", // browse with localhost:7031/api/product
                //routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",  // browse with localhost:7031/product
                 defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
      );
```

Controller/ProductController.cs :

```
    public class ProductController : ApiController
    {
        NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();

        public List<Product> GetAll()
        {
            return db.Products.ToList<Product>();// ;
        }
```

View/ViewProduct.aspx :

```
    <script src="Script/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#<%= cviewproduct.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
            getProducts();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });

    function getProducts() {
        $.getJSON("/api/product",
                function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        //var str = val.ProductName;
                        // alert(str);

                        var row = '<tr> <td>' + val.ProductName + '</td><td>' + val.ProductID + '</td><tr/>';

                        $(row).appendTo($('#tblproduct'));


                    });
                });
    }
</script>
```

Bellow Is The Result of product Controller via 'http://localhost:7031/api/product'  :

[image]

Bellow Is The Result of getProducts() function :

[image]

Please help me.

Any idea or suggestion ?

Comment: can u show us the complete JSON object returned by the service

Comment: thank's for the replay, can you please help me how to produce the returned of json object

Comment: Try viewing the response in the developer tools tab of your browser (Firefox Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools)

Comment: i followed your sugestion, but there is nothing error or any response on chrome console developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `$.getJSON("/api/product", ...`, you are not getting back XML as you posted. You are getting back JSON.

As a first step, I suggest you download and install [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp). Open it, and use the Composer tab to execute a GET for `http://localhost:7031/api/product`. That should show you the JSON returned, which will be different from the XML. Post that JSON to your original question and we should be able to help further.

My guess is that the JSON is not properly formatted. What does your WebApiConfig.cs class look like?

**Update**

Yes, there is a better way. First, create an ApiModel (ApiModel is to WebAPI what ViewModel is to MVC):

```
public class ProductApiModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, return this instead of an entity from your controller:

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductApiModel> GetAll()
    {
        var products = db.Products
            .OrderBy(x => x.ProductID)
            .Select(x => new ProductApiModel
            {
                ProductId = x.ProductID,
                ProductName = x.ProductName
            });
        return products;
    }
}
```

If you used [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper), you could make your controller code a bit shorter:

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductApiModel> GetAll()
    {
        var entities = db.Products.OrderBy(x => x.ProductID);
        var models = Mapper.Map<ProductApiModel[]>(entities);
        return models;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank's for your reply.. I will try with Fiddler2 according to which you have suggested, my project does not contain any WebApiConfig.cs file, but my route table define on global.asax (see above), can give me a good link/reference about that config.

Comment: Hi..danludwig  Thank's For Your Suggestion.. AutoMapper.. Solved My Problem.

Answer (score 0):

After do some research, i finaly found (Please Correct Me, if i'm wrong) :
JavaScriptSerializer failed to serialize the entire objects tree from relations 
between the entity and other entities (Product and Catagory).

So .. I made ​​some changes to my code, and the results are as expected

---

**Controller/ProductController.cs :**

**From :**

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();

    public List<Product> GetAll()
    {
        return db.Products.ToList<Product>();// ;
    }
```

**To :**

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{

   public string GetAll()
    {
        var product = db.Products.OrderBy(x => x.ProductID).Select(x => new
                     {
                         ProductId = x.ProductID,
                         ProductName = x.ProductName
                     });
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
    }
```

---

**View/ViewProduct.aspx :**

**From :**

```
function getProducts() {
        $.getJSON("/api/product",
                function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        var row = '<tr> <td>' + val.ProductName 
            + '</td><td>' + val.ProductID + '</td><tr/>';
                        $(row).appendTo($('#tblproduct'));

                    });
                });
```

**To :**

```
$.getJSON("/api/product",
                function (data) {
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each(obj, function (key, val) {
                        var row = '<tr> <td>' + val.ProductId 
        + '</td><td>' + val.ProductName + '</td><tr/>';
                        $(row).appendTo($('#tblproduct'));
                    });
                });
```

---

Or... is there a better way than this,

if I still want to pass an entity object instead of a string object
(List  GetAll ()... instead GetAll string ()....)

Regards,

Andrian

Comment: In short, yes, there is a better way. WebApi has javascript serialization built in, so you should not need to use JsonConvert. However, you don't want to return entities directly from your controllers. Return ApiModels (like ViewModels in MVC). You could use AutoMapper to make this easier, but you don't have to. See my updated answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14219166/304832

Answer (score 0):

So.. This My Final Working Code

**Models :**

namespace MyLabs1.Models

```
{
    public class ProductApi
    {
        [Key]
        public Int32 ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller/ProductController.cs :**

```
public IEnumerable<ProductApi> getall()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductApi>();
        var entities = db.Products.OrderBy(x => x.ProductID).ToList();
        var models = Mapper.Map<ProductApi[]>(entities);
        return models;
    }
```

**OR**

```
public List<ProductApi> GetAll()
{
    var products = db.Products
        .OrderBy(x => x.ProductID)
        .Select(x => new ProductApi
        {
            ProductID = x.ProductID,
            ProductName = x.ProductName
        }).ToList();
    return products;
}
```

**View/ViewProduct.aspx :**

> ```
> function getProducts() {
>     $.getJSON("/api/product",
>             function (data) {
>                 $.each(data, function (key, val) {
>                     var row = '<tr> <td>' + val.ProductName + '</td><td>' + val.ProductID + '</td><tr/>';
>                     $(row).appendTo($('#tblproduct'));
>                 });
>             });
>    }
> ```

**Hope This Will Be Helpful to Others**

Regards,

Andrian